# Netbeans : Find which jtable is active

Tags: java, swing

I have a form with multiple jtables (table1, ..tableN) and a button for edit row.

How can I get which jtable is active ?

eg for the first table  I know that I have to write

```
EditForm form1  = new EditForm(listArray.get(table1.getSelectedRow()));
form1.setVisible(true);
```

Moreover, I would like to ask what event should I use to enable edit button in form only if a row of a jtable is selected ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Checkout the `Focus` based events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a ListSelectionListener to all the tables.

When the selection of a row is made an event will be generated. You can then get the table from the event and save it as an instance variable in your class.

Then you can reference this variable in the ActionListener of your button.

Comment: I am trying something like the following, but it does not work.

    public Form() {
        initComponents();

ListSelectionModel model1 = Table1.getSelectionModel();
model1.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

@Override
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
     if(!= model1.isSelectionEmpty())
        TabSelected = 1;
  }
};)

}

I am sorry I am new in java

Comment: 1) Don't post code in a comment. As you can see it is not readable. 2) I have no idea what "does not work" means. Does the listener generate an event. Does the if statement execute. 3) Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. So to learn a concept you simplify the problem. So all you need is a frame with a JTable. Then you can test your listener. If you post what you tried we might be able to spot the problem.